# error occurred while deploying a module to iot edge device (ErrorCode:Argumentinvalid)

Tags: json, azure, azure-iot-hub, modbus, azure-iot-edge

I'm trying to deploy a Modbus module from iot hub to iot edge device but i'm having some difficulties.

Docker Image I used:

```
mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge/modbus:1.0
```

Container Create Option:
(I have used this beacuse i'm using this module to read data from a modbus rtu device)

```
{
  "HostConfig": {
    "Devices": [
      {
        "PathOnHost": "/dev/ttyS0", 
        "PathInContainer": "/dev/ttyS0",
        "CgroupPermissions": "rwm"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Module Twine Setings:

```
{  
      "properties.desired":{
        "PublishInterval": "5000",
        "SlaveConfigs": {
          "Slave01": {
            "SlaveConnection": "<IPV4 address>",
            "TcpPort": "502",
            "RetryCount": "10",
            "RetryInterval": "100",
            "HwId": "PowerMeter-0a:01:01:01:01:01",
            "Operations": {
              "Op01": {
                "PollingInterval": "2000",
                "UnitId": "1",
                "StartAddress": "400001",
                "Count": "2",
                "CorrelationId": "MessageType1",
                "DisplayName": "Voltage"
              },
              "Op02": {
                "PollingInterval": "2000",
                "UnitId": "1",
                "StartAddress": "400002",
                "Count": "2",
                "CorrelationId": "MessageType2",
                "DisplayName": "Current"
              }
            }
          },
          "Slave02": {
            "SlaveConnection": "/dev/ttyS0",
            "RetryCount": "10",
            "RetryInterval": "50",
            "HwId": "mfm",
            "BaudRate": "9600",
            "DataBits": "8",
            "StopBits": "1",
            "Parity": "NONE",
            "FlowControl": "NONE",
            "Operations": {
              "Op01": {
                "PollingInterval": "2000",
                "UnitId": "1",
                "StartAddress": "40001",
                "Count": "2",
                "DisplayName": "Voltage"
              },
              "Op02": {
                "PollingInterval": "2000",
                "UnitId": "1",
                "StartAddress": "40002",
                "Count": "2",
                "DisplayName": "Current"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Error:

```
Set Modules

An error occurred while submitting. The request contained incorrectly formatted information.

Details: ErrorCode:Argumentinvalid; Property or Tag name has invalid characters. Error in Property/Tag properties.desired. Must not contain Control Characters,

'.', '$', '#', or ''.
```

[GitHub link with tutorial](https://github.com/Azure/iot-edge-modbus/tree/a2ea4a5ff15b9be300a266df9e61153ebd9c4af9)

Comment: [Writing commands to IoT Edge Modbus Modules](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure/writing-commands-to-iot-edge-modbus-modules/m-p/149366), [Introduction to the microsoft/azureiotedge-modbus-tcp IoTEdge Module](https://sandervandevelde.wordpress.com/2017/12/27/introduction-to-the-microsoft-azureiotedge-modbus-tcp-iotedge-module/) and [Character '#' is not permitted in Device Twin property Keys](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-java/issues/243)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you should make "desired" a separate node in your JSON.  e.g.:

[image]